# Getting the "Object reference not set" error when using a trigger?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a trigger script attached to my player and when I enter the trigger of an object with the tag `Target`, a bool `willGrab` is called where I am then able to carry that specific object. I use `other.transform.parent` so that I can have as many `Target` objects as desired which will all perform the same action flawlessly.

So for example I have 5 objects all with the same tag, I can enter the trigger of one of them, perform the carry action, and then exit that trigger and freely enter the trigger of any of the other objects (or that same object) and perform the exact same carry action. Every time I exit one of those triggers, the mainObject Transform in my inspector turns None (Transform) as it should, and then gets updated to the relevant object once I enter any of the 5 triggers.

The issue is that when I exit any trigger, I immediately get several "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" errors. I know where it is coming from, it is the line `mainObject = null` inside of my `OnTriggerExit`. I had this error a month ago and I fixed it, I believe that I changed the `null` to something else and the error went away, but I altered an entire block of my code and unknowingly changed that line so now I can't remember what I did.

```
Transform mainObject;

public Transform MainObject
{
    get { return mainObject; }
}

public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

    if (!other.CompareTag("Target")) return;

    willGrab = true;
    mainObject = other.transform.parent;
}

public void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (!other.CompareTag("Target")) return;

    willGrab = false;
    mainObject = null;   
}
```

Edit: I removed the `mainObject = null` line entirely and it seems to have fixed everything upon quick testing. I'm not sure if doing that was a bad idea though.

Comment: It's probably where you use `MainObject`. Check references to it and handle cases when it is `null`.

Comment: Yeah I just made a quick edit, I deleted that `mainObject = null` line and so far everything seems to work perfectly with no errors. The only concern I have is, is it a bad idea to just outright remove that line? Also, the error comes from another script where I use `MainObject.rotation` in my `Quaterion.RotateTowards`. But since every once in a while the `MainObject` turns `null`, that error pops up.

Comment: It depends on what `null` means for `MainObject`. You can set it to `None` (not sure what it means) if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your enter and exit trigger should be working fine. Check `mainObject` who access the variable and check if null. Assume you access `mainObject` to get `CharacterController` let's say like this.

```
private void Update()
{
    var controller = mainObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}
```

It should write like this.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (mainObject == null)
        return;
    var controller = mainObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}
```

To find `mainObject` reference, just right click the variable and Find All Reference.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used Find All References prior to my post and they are all in my post, but there is one more reference in another script like so: `MainObject.rotation` which I use inside a `Quaternion.RotateTowards` to rotate my player towards the `MainObject`. That is actually where the error is coming from. But when I removed `mainObject = null` from the code in my post, the error went away. I'm not sure if my solution was correct though

Comment: Well, if that working then it's correct.

Comment: @dangoqut132 well depends ... do you still ant to rotate towards the object even though it is not touching the trigger anymore? Otherwise your solution is wrong and you rather want to check whether it is assigned and only rotate if it is